# DBPedia: trouble with dbo:region property

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

I am trying to collect all musicians who are active in the US from DBPedia using a SPARQL query. I have tried the following query but it returns an empty list:

```
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT distinct ?person where {?person a dbo:MusicalArtist . ?person dbp:region "United States"} LIMIT 100
```

I'm not sure what is going wrong here. I've tried matching string values on other properties like foaf:name without any problems so I'm not sure why the "region" property isn't working.

Comment: why do you think that musicians have such a property? I mean, did you check any musician? I don't see that such a property value exists. And why do you think it has to be a string literal instead of a URI?

Comment: I based my question off of musicians like this: http://dbpedia.org/page/Nicki_Minaj

You can see that the value for "dbp:region" is "United States."

Comment: true. But many others don't. You won't get a complete result that way. Anyways, the issue is the missing literal type: `PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>
SELECT distinct ?person where {?person a dbo:MusicalArtist . ?person dbp:region "United States"^^rdf:langString} LIMIT 100
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved! Thanks to @UninformedUser in the comments above.

We just have to specify the literal type for string matching.

```
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> 
SELECT distinct ?person where {?person a dbo:MusicalArtist . ?person dbp:region "United States"^^rdf:langString} LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 1):

For me this code worked -

```
PREFIX dbp: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> 
PREFIX dbr: <http://dbpedia.org/resource/>
PREFIX dbo: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>

SELECT distinct ?person where 
{
    ?person a dbo:MusicalArtist . 
    ?person dbp:region "United States"@en .
} 
LIMIT 100
```